# Jest to test JS in a php file

Tags: javascript, php, unit-testing, jestjs

I need to test some javascript I have in a php file (cannot be turned in any other extension file, for a few reasons, including it also contains php).

How can I achieve this using Jest?

For example, I have tried the following:

```
const parse = require('regenerator-runtime/runtime');

const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

test("test JavaScript code in PHP file", async () => {
    //create a mock of the DOM
    const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><body>
    <script>
    // Add JS code from php file in here 
    let sum = function sum(a, b) {
        return a + b
    }
    </script>
    </body>`);
    global.document = dom.window.document;
    global.window = dom.window;
    global.navigator = dom.window.navigator;
    // run your tests here
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

Unfortunately gives me an error:

`ReferenceError: sum is not defined`

How can I test the JS within the mock of the DOM since it is in it's own scope?

Is there a better way to test javascript in a php file?

Comment: You are required to enable the [execution of scripts](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#executing-scripts), they are disabled by default. If parsed correctly, the sum function should be available at `dom.window.sum()`.

Comment: does that not pause a security risk? Would it not be better to simply have a copy of the javascript in the global scope of the test file and test it there?

Comment: You could use [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/), [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) or other similar tools.